# Spring: create mocks instead of real objects

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, playframework, mockito

I'm using Spring annotation based configuration in my Play application.

Controllers and DAOs are Spring beans. Controller and DAO layers are defined with different Spring profiles and each layer could be disabled separately.

I'd like to test controller layer in isolation from DAO layer. I've disabled DAO profile and redefined each of DAO beans as a Mockito mock. From functional point of view it works fine, the only thing I don't like is defining mocks manually like this:

```
@Configuration
@Import(AppContext.class)
public class TestAppContext {

    @Bean
    public DaoA getDaoA(){
        return mock(DaoA.class);
    }

    //... all dependencies are re-defined manually
}
```

Is there a way to define package (like with `@ComponentScan` annotation)
and get all beans in that package as mocks instead of real objects?

UPD:
I'm running tests with `FakeApplication` (https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/api/java/play/test/FakeApplication.html), so context is started not in the test level, but inside fake application startup.

```
public class ControllerTest extends WithApplication {

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        start(fakeApplication(new GlobalSettings(){
            private ApplicationContext appContext;

            public void onStart(Application app) {
                appContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(TestAppContext.class);
            }

            @Override
            public <A> A getControllerInstance(Class<A> clazz) throws Exception {
                return appContext.getBean(clazz);
            }
        }));
    }

    ...
}
```

I did it like this because I wan't to make the test more reliable and test how controller works in real environment:

```
@Test
public void testControllerMethod() {
    Result result = route(fakeRequest(GET, "/controller/method"));
    assertThat(result).is(...);
}
```

Comment: If you reconfigure your controller to use constructor injection instead of field injection, you can avoid the need for the context entirely and just pass mocks to the constructor.

Comment: I'm already using constructor injection. The reason I need entirely context is because it's required by test framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the number of dependencies you need to mock is huge, you can also use [spring-auto-mock](https://github.com/rinoto/spring-auto-mock).

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { AutoMockRegistryPostProcessor.class, RestOfClasses.class, ... })
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class YourTest {
  ...
}
```

As you are creating the `ApplicationContext` on your own, you can register the postprocessor programmatically:

```
        public void onStart(Application app) {
            appContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(TestAppContext.class);
            appContext.getBeanFactory().addBeanPostProcessor(new AutoMockRegistryPostProcessor())
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Please see my update regarding context initialisation. It seems that SpringJUnit4ClassRunner is not applicable here.

Answer (score 0):

1. Mark your unit-test with @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
2. Mark your tested class as @InjectMock
3. Mark you Dao class as @Mock
4. Make use of Mockito in your project